# R Session fails while debugging inside the observeEvent

Tags: r, debugging, shiny, breakpoints, abort

I have created a modular shiny application. I have put the `browser()` function inside an `observeEvent()`. As I hit the button for which I have to perform the action, the `browser` hits and the R Studio session aborts. The same thing happens when I put the breakpoint inside the same `observeEvent`. What could be the possible reason and solution to this?

Just for reference, please find the code below

```
observeEvent(input$btn_scheme_details_output, {
      hot = isolate(input$scheme_details_edit)
      
      browser()

      SchemeDetailsUpdated <- data.frame()

      if(!is.null(hot)){
        SchemeDetailsUpdated <- ModifyColumns(hot_to_r(input$scheme_details_edit), 'db')
        print(SchemeDetailsUpdated)
      }
      
      sendSweetAlert(
        session = session,
        title = "Success !!",
        text = "The updated values are successfully saved and submitted.",
        type = "success"
      )
      
    })
```

Comment: I've had the same problem on rstudio server for 2+ years in R 4.0.3. Browser() works fine on 3.6.3 or on R4 on desktop Rstudio. I haven't found any solution yet.